# I disabled secure boot and I get an error message when I boot. Ubuntu 19.10. This is the error generated after updating the kernel

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

My Ubuntu19.10 shows the following prompt when booting,I'm looking for a solution, my PC works,I just don't want to see an error,If you have encountered a similar issue and have already resolved it,Please take a moment to tell me, thank you!

```
[    0.683181] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    0.683197] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    0.683659] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    0.683672] Couldn't get UEFI MokListRT
[    0.684138] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    0.684151] Couldn't get UEFI dbx list
```

Answer (score -1):

Just now, the problem was resolved.

Edit file:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Modify the value of this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 splash"
```

then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

nice!!!

[original](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-suppress-kernel-boot-error-messages/10617/7)